# Automatic days count in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, datediff

I am trying to find a way to get Auto Calculated No of days between two days.

Example: If I create an entry let's say ID is 500 on `1st July, 2016` and saved it.
Again, after 15 days, i.e. I opened the ID 500 on `15th July, 2016`, the Value field should show as "15"  including 15th July. In the same way, if I open the ID on `20th July, 2016`, it should show "20".

I tried with datediff function but it is not auto calculating.

```
Me.txtndays.Text = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Now, metxtdtenter.Text)
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `I tried with datediff function but it is not auto calculating.` - Define "auto calculating".

Comment: Where does `1st July, 2016` come from?  Is it a value saved along with the Id?  Is that what is in `metxtdtenter`?  Why is it text?  If you want dates to act like dates uses a `DateTime` type.

Comment: [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx) doesn't take strings as parameter, you should compare with proper dates.

Comment: @VisualVincent thank you very much for your reply. I have already date of entry and no of days columns. I wanted to auto calculate the difference between the date of entry and Now(). when i opened the entry.

Comment: @Plutonix It was actually date field (datetime).

Comment: `metxtdtenter.Text` is neither a date type nor a field

Comment: You have shared too little code if you want help with automatically calculating it.

Comment: @Plutonix so, i have declared in a wrong way? like metxtdtenter.text? Actually, the field is a datepicker bound to a grid table.

Comment: I thought you were trying to compare a db date field to Now() - how does a DateTimePicker come into play?

Comment: @Plutonix you are correct. I am getting data to the fields by Bounding to Datagridview.

Comment: I'm sorry, your problem is very poorly documented.  DataGridView, DateTimePickers, textboxes flying around, coming out of nowhere and we have no idea what maps to what.  Whatever control shows the DB Date, use the Date form of that in the code Matt provided.

Answer (score 3):

Well there are actually 14 days between 1st July and 15th July.

To calculate this you can subtract one date from the other which will result in a `TimeSpan` and then find the `TotalDays` like this:

```
    Dim originalDate As Date = #2016-07-01# 'get this value from the database
    Dim testDate As Date = #2016-07-15# 'this is the date you want to compare to. Use DateTime.Now to use the current date
    Dim daysBetween = (testDate - originalDate).TotalDays '14
```

Comment: Date literals need to be in invariant culture form `#7/1/2016#`

Comment: @Plutonix - not anymore they don't

Comment: is that a VS2015 thing?  Thats great.  I always thought that form made more sense.

Comment: @Plutonix - yes I believe it is a VB14.0 language feature. I was just trying (and failing to find a reference) Here it is in the Format Requirements section https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx

Comment: @MattWilko thank you very much. But, does it do auto calculation. If I retrieve data after some days, the No of Days field has to show the difference.

Comment: yes , you need to read the values from your database into date variables. My example has these hard coded

Comment: @MattWilko thank you. I will test it and will get back to you.